# Add a dynamic property to a class in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a class defined like this:

```
class classA {
    id: number;
    name: string;

    constructor(data){
        this.id = data?.id || 0;
        this.name = data?.name || '';
    }
}
```

Now I want to add a dynamic property to this class definition and assign it (the class definition) to another variable.

For instance a variable has this class definition.

```
const classDef = classA;
```

Now what I want is that the `classDef` has an added property whose name is defined in another variable `parentFieldName`;

So for e.g.

```
const parentFieldName = 'parent_id';
```

???? some magic code here ????

And the class definition in `classDef` becomes:

```
class {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    parent_id: number;

    constructor(data){
        this.id = data?.id || 0;
        this.name = data?.name || '';
        this.parent_id = data?.parent_id || 0;
    }
}
```

Only the field name `parent_id` is dynamic, while I know the field type will be `numeric` and it will be initialized with `0`.

Thanks.

Comment: Remember you can do not only `this.x` but `this['x']` which means you can do `this[classDef.parentFieldName]`

Comment: How is this related to React?

Comment: @tadman this is accessing the object, I want to edit the class not its objects, actually the class definition is used later for some processing

Comment: @Andy I mentioned React so that if there is any helper in react library, it can be used

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question, you want to **add new property to the first class and then assign that class to a new variable**. I think you can **extend that class to create a new class**. This will give you desired results. Try this:-

```js
  class classA {
    constructor(data) {
      this.id = data?.id || 0;
      this.name = data?.name || '';
    }
  }
  
  class classB extends classA {
    constructor(data, parentId) {
      super(data);
      this.parentId = data?.parentId || 0
    }
  }

  let data2 = {
    id: 1,
    name: "john",
    parentId: 10
  };
  const classb = new classB(data2);
  console.log(classb);
```

Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: I tried extending the class, but somehow it did not work in my scenario. Actually the `classDef` variable thing makes it a bit complicated. I will give that another try.

Comment: I think you are using in typescript. Just use the same logic it will work.

Comment: Does not work because the class property assignment is also dynamic and thus the new class declaration does not work separately by extending the old class, I dont thing it is even possible to do that

Comment: I would advice one thing. If what you want to achieve is not possible using this approach then definitely think differently. Think about a different approach for your desired result. Can you share the scenario?

Comment: The situation is very generic and thus the code is very dynamic. Therefore to make it work, I had to provide an option where a custom class can be supplied and that worked. So if a property is required to be added for a scenario, the user of the library has to provide a custom class for it. Would have been super if the class could be created on runtime by the library itself.